# Bug in community package?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I highly suspect that there is a bug in `community` package. It in in the calculation in module score. I looked at the `Louvain` algorithm [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0476.pdf) and find some anomaly. Here is the problem-
In the equation of `Q`

[image: Equation for Q]

there is `k_ik_j/2m` and after after multiplying the outside `1/2m` it should be `k_ik_j/4 sqr(m)`, But if you go the the `modularity()` function of the package, the code is like this- `sqr(k_ik_j/4m)`. See line number 131 and the is the line-

```
  res += (inc.get(com, 0.) / (2. * links)) -(deg.get(com, 0.) / (2. * links)) ** 2
```

But, according to the equation it should have been like this-

```
res += (inc.get(com, 0.) / (2. * links)) - deg.get(com, 0.) / (2. * links) ** 2
```

I tested on some toy graph to check the modularity score of best cluster and the second corrected code giving the highest modularity for the best partition. But, the first code(the wrong one(probably)), giving low modularity score for the best partition.

Those above was what I got after reading the paper, testing with some graph and understanding and debugging the `modularity()` function.

My question is, is my finding correct? can anybody check it? If anybody need some more information or clarification, I can provide.

I am using the 0.8 version of [python-louvine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-louvain) package.

Comment: In case this is the same thing, [here's a github page](https://github.com/taynaud/python-louvain/issues) where you can raise issues if you think you've found a bug. (This is as far as my domain knowledge goes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that second part is k_i * k_j / (4 sqr(m)), with k_i the degree of the community i. But you are only considering case where i==j, and thus it become:

k_i * k_i /4 sqr(m) == (k_i / (2 m)) ** 2

With your equation, I think you were only considering k_i and forget the k_j.